# JQuery Dynamically adding a element and then updating it

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to do a little script to insert after a textbox or textarea how many characters the user has used and whats remaining. In order to do this I'm looking for DOM objects that have the MVC3 added data- validation.

I want my JQuery script to insert a  tag automatically after the textbox and then update it after every keypress. I can get it to insert the  tag but I can't work out how to get it to update it. I've added the code below:

```
// controls character input/counter
$("[data-val-length-max]").keyup(function (e) {
var $this = $(this),
    charLength = $this.val().length,
    charLimit = $this.attr("data-val-length-max");
// Displays count
var $chars = $this.nextAll("<span>");

if ($chars != "null") {
    $chars.html(charLength + " of " + charLimit + " characters used");
}
else {
    $this.after("<span>" + charLength + " of " + charLimit + " characters used" + "</span>").addClass("block");
}
// Alert when max is reached
//    if ($this.val().length > charLimit) {
//        $this.nextAll("span").html("<strong>You may only have up to " + charLimit + " characters.</strong>");
//    }
});
```

I'm still very new to JQuery to I apologise at what is probably some poor coding! Its probably worth stating that there will be multiple instances of character limited textboxes to a single page so the script needs to make sure it only adds/updates the span for its self not any other elements.

Comment: you can use jQueires change()-but on textbox only fires on lost focus, not keypress.. but you could use `$('#id').keypress(function() {
  alert("Handler for .keypress() called.") });`

Comment: Try using $chars.text() if you are just updating text instead of $chars.html()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your if condition:

> ```
> $chars != "null"
> ```

```
$chars.size() // size returns 0 if it found no elements
```

I got it working by fixing some other problems for you in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mAMM5/1/